# Store a second value as a variable based on a dropdown menu selection

Tags: php, database, variables, drop-down-menu

I have two tables: `event_title` lists the Event_title_ID, title, and date of upcoming events, and `event_reg` stores data from a submitted form.

I am using a WHILE loop to get data from the `event_title` table to populate a dropdown menu:

```
<select id="title" name="Event_title_ID">
<option value="0">Please Select One</option>
<?php
$q = "SELECT Event_title_ID, title, date FROM event_title ORDER BY date ASC";
    $r = mysqli_query($connection, $q);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['Event_title_ID'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option>No event to register for at this time</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

After running validation, I am setting the $row['Event_title_ID'] as $Event_title_ID and inserting it into the `event_reg` table.

Based on the user's choice of dropdown items, I need to also store the `$row['title']` as a variable `$title`, so that it can be called on in an email that is sent to the admin.

I am not sure how to store the second value based on the choice that the user has made from the  value in the dropdown menu.

****UPDATE****

Thank you to [@shut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2496496/shut) for the answer.  Here's my code:

In the form:

```
<select id="title" name="Event_title_ID">
<option value="0">Please Select One</option>

<?php // retrieve all the events from the event_title table
$q = "SELECT Event_title_ID, title, date FROM event_title ORDER BY date ASC";
$r = mysqli_query($connection, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['Event_title_ID'] .'-'.$row['title']. '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<option>No event to register for at this time</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

In the validation:

```
<?php
    $errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['Event_title_ID']) && $_POST['Event_title_ID'] == '0') 
        {
            $errors[] = '<p id="eventErr">Please select an event.</p>';
        } else {
            $event = explode('-' , $_POST['Event_title_ID']);
            $Event_title_ID = $event[0];
            $title = $event[1];
        }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [hidden fields](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden)?

Comment: Yes, I did try using hidden fields - I should have mentioned that. When trying to add it to the syntax though, the results never came back as hoped.  For example, adding a hidden field directly after the closing option tag within the while loop resulted in only one option being presented in the dropdown, and the rest outside of the dropdown.  Do you know how to mark up a dropdown using hidden fields so this behavior is corrected?

Comment: Pretty sure you would have to put your hidden field outside of your dropdown. You could then update the value of the hidden field every time the dropdown `selectedIndex` changes, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both event_title and event_title_id on a select option value and after validation explode that value.
**Example**

```
 echo '<option value="' . $row['Event_title_ID'] .'-'.$row['title']. '">' . $row['title'] . '</option>';
```

and after validation use

```
$event = explode('-' , $_POST['Event_title_ID']);
$Event_title_ID=$event[0];
$title=$event[1];
```

Comment: This did the trick!  I'll post my code below.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I often use a spam_scrubber function and the following syntax in my validation: $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($scrubbed['title']));  Is there a way to add this to the code you posted above?